# multiple markers not plotting

Tags: html, api, markers

I am trying to plot multiple markers using the map API but the map is not plotting, I have posted the code below, hoping someone will help me trouble shoot.
Initially when I had only the contractor and the latlongs variables, the map and markers were plotting, but when I added the client and name variables, the map refused to plot.
I am new to programming and know that I am missing out on something here.
Thanks.

var locations = [
          ['Contractor: Lee Construction Ltd', -1.32021,36.82789, 'Client: County', 'Name: project 1', 1],
          ['Contractor: Intex Africa Limited', -1.27942, 36.83980, 'Client: County', 'Name: project 1', 2],
          ['Contractor: Oriental Company Limited', -1.3410701, 36.75760, 'Client: county', 'Name:Project2', 3],
          ['Contractor: Axis Architects', -1.29805, 36.78690, 'Client: National govt', 'Name:Project 3', 4],
          ['Contractor: Becam Properties Ltd', -1.24511, 36.76830, 'Client: Local Govt', 'Name:Project 4', 5],
          ['Contractor: Chania Gardens Limited', -1.2169, 36.86180, 'Client: NGO', 'Name:Project 5', 6],
          ['Contractor: Dimension Architects', -1.23793, 36.80990, 'Client: Parastatal', 'Name:Project 6', 7],
          ['Contractor: Gibb Africa Ltd', -1.25713, 36.88110, 'Client: Local Govt', Name:Project 7', 8],
          ['Contractor: Selengei Limited', -1.2830, 36.81780, 'Client: NGO', 'Name:Project 7', 9],
          ['Contractor: Msingi Africa Ltd', -1.2556601, 36.8325005, 'Client: Local Govt', 'Name:Project 8', 10],
          ['Contractor: Frame Consultants Ltd', -1.31691, 36.7182007, 'Client: County govt', 'Name:Project 9', 11],
          ['Contractor: Mentor Group', -1.29862, 36.7574997, 'Client: National Govt', 'Name:project 10', 12],
          ['Contractor: CUAK Developers', -1.27955, 36.8095016, 'Client: Private', 'Name:Project 11', 13],
          ['Contractor: East Africa Ltd', -1.29074, 36.8824997,  'Client: Private', 'Name:Project 12', 14],
          ['Contractor: Montezuma Limited', -1.31801, 36.8642006,'Client: Private', 'Name:Project 13', 15]

        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-1.32021,36.82789),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please update your full code over here http://jsfiddle.net/3zjmztdn/ or update your question

Answer (score 0):

Hey please check the Script you will see the multiple marker on the map

Here is the working html FILE https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rwnro6vz9d9orv/googlemaps.html?dl=0

```
    var map;
    var locations = [
        ['Contractor: Lee Construction Ltd', -1.32021, 36.82789, 'Client: County', 'Name: project 1', 1],
        ['Contractor: Intex Africa Limited', -1.27942, 36.83980, 'Client: County', 'Name: project 1', 2],
        ['Contractor: Oriental Company Limited', -1.3410701, 36.75760, 'Client: county', 'Name:Project2', 3],
        ['Contractor: Axis Architects', -1.29805, 36.78690, 'Client: National govt', 'Name:Project 3', 4],
        ['Contractor: Becam Properties Ltd', -1.24511, 36.76830, 'Client: Local Govt', 'Name:Project 4', 5],
        ['Contractor: Chania Gardens Limited', -1.2169, 36.86180, 'Client: NGO', 'Name:Project 5', 6],
        ['Contractor: Dimension Architects', -1.23793, 36.80990, 'Client: Parastatal', 'Name:Project 6', 7],
        ['Contractor: Gibb Africa Ltd', -1.25713, 36.88110, 'Client: Local Govt', 'Name:Project 7', 8],
        ['Contractor: Selengei Limited', -1.2830, 36.81780, 'Client: NGO', 'Name:Project 7', 9],
        ['Contractor: Msingi Africa Ltd', -1.2556601, 36.8325005, 'Client: Local Govt', 'Name:Project 8', 10],
        ['Contractor: Frame Consultants Ltd', -1.31691, 36.7182007, 'Client: County govt', 'Name:Project 9', 11],
        ['Contractor: Mentor Group', -1.29862, 36.7574997, 'Client: National Govt', 'Name:project 10', 12],
        ['Contractor: CUAK Developers', -1.27955, 36.8095016, 'Client: Private', 'Name:Project 11', 13],
        ['Contractor: East Africa Ltd', -1.29074, 36.8824997, 'Client: Private', 'Name:Project 12', 14],
        ['Contractor: Montezuma Limited', -1.31801, 36.8642006, 'Client: Private', 'Name:Project 13', 15]
    ];
    var k = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(43, 0)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map($('#mapcanvas')[0], mapOptions);
        var marker = null;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[k][1], locations[k][1]);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: newPoint,
                    map: map
                });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: locations[k][0]
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
                k++;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks much Mitul for your help, but the code in the dropbox folder is not opening.

Comment: Can you please try https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rwnro6vz9d9orv/googlemaps.html?dl=1

Comment: Thanks, managed to open it, but its just opening the map and not showing the markers. You centered the map somewhere in France, but I changed the center coords to fall within Nairobi, still map but no markers.

Comment: Just add the `map.setCenter(lat, long)`